# Text auto-complete in text box [image attached inside]

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am designing a website. I am using the following code for a search box:

```
<form method="get" action="search.php">
     <input type="text" id="search" name="search" onKeyUp="showSuggestions();">
     <input type="submit" id="submitsearch" value="Search">
</form>
```

For the search string entered by the user, I am showing suggestions. My problem is that my web-browser also showing suggestions of previously entered search strings (image below). You can see that Firefox suggestion are in foreground and my search suggestions are in background.

**My question:** Is there any code which will prevent a text box to remember history? Or anything I can do to fix this?

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 3):

You can [prevent the default](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.preventDefault) action:

```
function onKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var code;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
    e.target.value += character;
    return false;
}
```

You are telling the browser that you are going to handle the actions for this event.

EDIT: Since this is the event that handles the key press, we need to add that key that is pressed to the input ourselves because we are preventing the default action.

Comment: What my HTML would be? `onKeyDown="onKeyDown(event);"` is not letting me enter anything.

Comment: Thanks Joey for the help. But I think we need to consider for IE and other browsers also. :)

Answer (score 3):

I just saw the source code of a website with similar functionality. It used the following:

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" autocomplete="off">
```

It worked for me!!!